# Android build sizes changed?

Tags: android, codenameone, parse4cn1

We have built an app on Thursday(21 Jan 2016), which was 3MB in size. Last night(27 Jan 2016) we have built the same app without changes for an production environment which was 5.1MB in size. We noticed new libs appeared in the APK. This has caused our app to behave differently than before (the 21 Jan build).

Is there something we need to do, to not have these changes in our app?

Comment: Have you checked your gradle, or any script that you can make?
I use to toggle the release and the debug, adding different libraries depending of the phase of the app.

Comment: Are you using `+` on libraries version numbers?

Comment: Also check if you flipped the switch on `android.includeGPlayServices`. if you don't need it, add a build hint `android.includeGPlayServices=false`

Comment: @Sandro, where is the + in library version numbers?

Answer (score 0):

During those dates we were on a code freeze so while we did make a couple of changes they were very minor. If you have both APK's there are many reverse engineering tools for APK's on the market, you can inspect both and clarify why the size change happened.

Is it possibly due to reduced obfuscation or as Diamond suggested in the comments the inclusion of google play services?

Comment: Hi Shai, I have set rim.obfuscation = false, as well as android.includeGPlayServices=false in the build hints. And yes, the build is set for release, not debug. And the size stays the same.

Comment: The rim obfuscation has nothing to do with Android. I suggest inspecting the APK and seeing what triggered the size change.

Comment: I have spoken to our Product Manager, he says it looks like no obfuscation was done.

Comment: Did you disable it in some way? Are you using the debug build? Its easy to see if its a debug build by the -debug or lack of -release at the end of the file name.

Comment: Hi Shai, No did not disable it. I went to the project settings, ticked debug. It shows debug on the build server. Then I went and ticked release, still debug on build server... I guess this is not right?

Comment: If you don't have a certificate configured you will only get debug builds. You need to configure a certificate keystore. If you ever submitted an app to google you can/should use the same certificate.